# Document not visible in embedded view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have a document which is visible in a view: View1

In another form I have a subform which has an embedded view with a embedded selection to View1.

Now this document is not visible in this embedded view how come?
I do also have other documents and those documents are visible.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the view indexes manually ? CTRL-Shift-F9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at the view on the same server that the embedded view is accessing? If not, that's your problem. Is the view categorized? Is the embedded view set to show a single category? If it is, that's probably your answer right there

Otherwise, you need to update your question with additional information. We need to know more about what you are doing, about that view, and about the document.

- Are you looking at the view on the web or in the Notes client?
- Same question for the document with embedded view?
- Was the document containing the embedded view created manually, or by script? (Show the code if it's the latter.)
- Was the document contained by the embedded view created manually, or by script. (Show the code if it's the latter.)
- Does it contain any Reader fields? Are you using the same ID to look at the view as you are

Comment: View is on the same server. The view is categorized. The documents in the view have a field called ID_Order this contains the document id of an order document. All documents in the view are categorized by this ID_Order. In the order document this embedded view is implemented so to see these documents of the embedded view.

Comment: If it is categorized, maybe you need to  @Trim the category and the key value....

Comment: Web or Notes client?

Comment: Notes client, also for the document with the embedded view. Document which contains embedded view is created by script, but normally it shows all documents in embedded view and the script has not been changed. The document contained by the embedded view is also created by script. Script is on Server A, document will be created on server B.Script is a bit big to share, but in summary what happens is docRequest.Form = "Request" .. fill docRequest fields with variables and eventually Call docRequest.save(true,true)

Comment: Hmmm... if the problem is on just one computer, I'd say delete the cache.ndk file and see what happens. Otherwise, maybe try { Load Updall Database filename.nsf -T "viewname" -R } on both server A and server B.

Comment: I have to take my words back "Are you looking at the view on the same server that the embedded view is accessing" Normally Yes, but only at my client it looks to the view which is in the local server. At other clients here in the company it looks to the correct server..